# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I was following the django documentation and making a simple poll app.     I have come across the following error :

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^polls/
    ^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these."
```

settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
app_name= 'polls' 
urlpatterns=[ 
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$',views.ResultsView.as_view(),name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$',views.vote,name='vote'),]
```

mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template import loader
from .models import Choice,Question
from django.template.loader import get_template
#def index(request):
#   return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index")
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='polls/index.html'
    context_object_name='latest_question_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[5:]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=Question
    template_name='polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Question
    template_name ='polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question=get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice= question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/details.html',
            {
            'question':question,
            'error_message' : "You didn't select a choice" ,

            })  
    else:
        selected_choice.votes+=1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{question.question_test }}
    </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

This link http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ shows a blank page with 3 bullets. (I have 3 questions in my database and their id's are 5,6,7 because I have been deleting and adding the questions.)

My admin works fine!

I'm new to Django and have been searching and asking around and have been stuck on it for a while now.

Comment: Now that you have posted your template, I can see that you have a typo. It should be `question.question_text`, not `question.question_test`.

Comment: Thank you sir @Alasdair for your valuable time. I didn't know the error was in this file..

Comment: This is te new error that I get when I click on vote after selecting a choice! Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
vote() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 147

Comment: That's a different issue, you should ask a new question rather than editing this one.

Comment: ok sir thank you :) @Alasdair

Answer (score 3):

You get the 404 on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` because you have not created any URL patterns for that url. You have included the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/`, because you have included the polls urls with

```
url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls')),
```

The empty bullets suggest that there is a problem with your `polls/index.html` template. It looks like you have a typo and have put `{{ question.question_test }}` instead of `{{ question.question_text }}`. Make sure that it exactly matches the template from the [tutorial 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something):

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no typo in your code. Putting space between inverted commas can also lead to this error. Just make sure you have put `path('',include('home.urls'))` and not `path(' ',include('home.urls'))`

Note: here `home.urls` is the name of my app in Django