# Why do I get an 404 Error in part 4 of the Django tutorial "Writing you first Django app"

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to complete the Django tutorial: Writing your first Django app. I am currently stuck on part 4.

After updating my template `polls/templates/polls/detail.html`, rewriting my `polls/views.py` and creating a `results.html` located at `polls/templates/polls/results.html`, I ran the server and tried to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/, but I get this Error:

```
Page not found (404)
No Question matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Raised by:  polls.views.detail
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/ [name='index']
polls/ <int:question_id>/ [name='detail']
The current path, polls/1/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I see that the error is raised by the html-file `detail` which looks like this:

```
<form action="{ url 'polls:vote' question.id }" method="post">
{ csrf_token }
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>

    { if error_message }<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{ endif }
    { for choice in question.choice_set.all }
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    { endfor }
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

My other two templates (html-files) `index` and `result` looks like this:

index.html:

```
{ if latest_question_list }
    <ul>
    { for question in latest_question_list }
        <li><a href="{ url 'polls:detail' question.id }">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    { endfor }
    </ul>
{ else }
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{ endif }
```

results.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{ for choice in question.choice_set.all }
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{ endfor }
</ul>

<a href="{ url 'polls:detail' question.id }">Vote again?</a>
```

When I try to run just http://127.0.0.1:8000, I get this Error Message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I tried to re-do the steps mentioned above (the first three steps of Part 4), making sure I use the correct paths, but I still get errors.

This is how my .py's look:

...\polls\views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {  # Redisplay the question voting form
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice"
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data.
        # This prevents data from being posted twice if a user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

.../polls/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),  # ex: /polls/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),  # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),  # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),  # ex: /polls/5/vote/
]
```

I have already looked at these questions:

[Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075145/page-not-found-404-request-methodget-request-urlhttp-127-0-0-18000)

[How to fix "Page not found (404)" error ("Django tried these URL patterns... The empty path didn't match any of these.")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536646/how-to-fix-page-not-found-404-error-django-tried-these-url-patterns-the)

[Page not found 404 on Django site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716185/page-not-found-404-on-django-site)

[Django Error: Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/helpdesk/login/?next=/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657001/django-error-page-not-found-404-request-methodget-request-urlhttp-127-0)

[How to fix "Page not found (404)" error ("Django tried these URL patterns... The empty path didn't match any of these.")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536646/how-to-fix-page-not-found-404-error-django-tried-these-url-patterns-the)

[Django Http404 message not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088549/django-http404-message-not-showing-up)

[Django Page not found(404) error (Library not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910991/django-page-not-found404-error-library-not-found)

[Django 404 error-page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102227/django-404-error-page-not-found)

(and many more) trying to figure this out for two days, but I can't seem to figure it out. I realize that this question probably is a duplicate, but I'm desperate, and I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't a problem with any of your HTML files or the URLs file. The clue to that can be found in the error message, here:
`Raised by:  polls.views.detail`

Which indicates that detail returns a 404 object. If we look at that part of views, you have this line:

`question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)`

My guess is that you don't have a question in the database with the ID 1 OR the database is empty. If either of those are true, get_object_or_404 would return a 404.

If there was an issue with the page actually not being found, you would not see the "Raised by" part of the error at all.

Comment: I have one question in the database, but it has id=7, how do I fix this? Because when I delete a question and create a new one it gets id += 1

Comment: There's no real way to "fix it". Auto incrementing primary keys are standard behavior afaik. You might be able to go in and change the primary key to 1 but I really would advise against that.


So the best answer is:
go to polls/7/

Comment: IT WORKED! I feel so relieved yet so stupid

Comment: Great to hear! And don't worry, I messed up way more than that when I first did the tutorial. Keep at it!